# how to create file names with a number that is generated randomly?

Tags: python-3.x, file

In the following code, I need to create the files holding the keys as having the transaction id as their names concatenated with "Priv" and with "Pub" to designate private key files and public key files that belong to the same transaction. Is that possible in python ? Thanks in advance.

```
class Transaction():
    def __init__(self,
     id=0,requester=0,requesterPK =0):
        self.id = id               #the uinque id or the hash of the transaction   
        self.requester = requester     
        self.requesterPK = requesterPK #Requester primary key
    def create_transactions():# Tx sender changes as the Tx propagates while Tx requester stays same        
        Tn = 5
        simTime = 5
        Psize= int(Tn * simTime) # Tx rate times simTime
        for i in range(Psize):
            ctrCreatedTx +=1
            # assign values for transactions' attributes. You can ignore some attributes if not of an interest, and the default values will then be used
            tx= Transaction()
            tx.id= random.randrange(100000000000)
            tx.requesterPK = RSA.generate(1024)
            f = open("Privkey.out", "wb")
            f.write(key.exportKey('PEM'))
            f.close()

            tx.requesterPubkey = key.publickey()
            f = open("Pubkey.out", "wb")
            f.write(pubkey.exportKey('OpenSSH'))
            f.close()
```

Comment: Why can't you just change the name of the file you are opening?
`open(f"{tx.id}Privkey.out", "wb")`?

Comment: Thanks : this works, however I would like to call a different function with the new file names to sign and verify the signature, like this: ``` def verify_Tx(self):
        verify_signature({tx.id}Pubkey.out,my_data.txt, {tx.id}my_data.sig) ``` How to do that please ?

Comment: Save the name of that file `privkey_name = f"{tx.id}Privkey.out"` and then use that variable to open the file and pass to whatever func you want.